# Using the <h2> as the title after sent?

Tags: php

Currently, I have a semi-dynamic system for my website's pages. `head.php` has all the tags before the content body, `foot.php` the tags after. Any page using the main theme will include head.php, then write the content, then output foot.php. Currently, to be able to set the title, I quickly set a variable `$title` before inclusion:

```
<?php $title = 'Untitled document'; include_once '../head.php'; ?>
<h2>Untitled document</h2>
Content here...
<?php include_once '../foot.php'; ?>
```

So that in head.php...

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?> | Delan Azabani</title>
```

However, this seems kludgy as the title is most of the time, the same as the content of the `h2` tag. Is there a way I can get PHP to read the content of `h2`, track back and insert it, then send the whole thing at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the h2 tags, you add the title like this:

```
 <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the **[HTML Simple DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)** to read the contents of `<h2`.

**Example:**

```
$title = str_get_html('<h2></h2>');
```

Now, you can use `$title` however, you like. Visit the their site for more info about it.